# calling viewdidload when using popViewController SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, viewdidload

I have a navigation view controller and I am using `popViewControllerAnimated(true)` to show the view controller shown before. It works but I need to call the `viewDidLoad` of the before shown view controller to reload a table view. The `viewDidLoad` is not called when using `popViewControllerAnimated(true)`. What should I do to call it then.

Comment: Perhaps you should be looking at viewDidAppear or viewWillAppear?  viewDidLoad was likely called much earlier than you are expecting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear` methods in view lifecycle to reload the data in your tableview.

Comment: Which are the differences between these two methods?

Comment: `viewWillAppear` is called just before the view is about the be rendered on screen. `viewDidAppear` is called after the view has already been rendered on screen.